# Is an all-pass filter a linear phase shift filter?

Tags: active-filter, phase-shift

Im in need of an application that needs to add linear phase shift to a signal similary to the one produced by a Bessel Filter, meaning constant delay, my question is: does a standard 1st order all pass filter provide a linear phase shift? if not, what circuit provides a linear phase shift similary to a Bessel filter, whilst providing linear amplitude response?

The type of all pass filter im familiar with is the following

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fD9LQ4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for relates to the term *group delay*. Here's an example of 1st order to higher order all-pass-filters: -

[image]

[Group delay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_delay_and_phase_delay) is: -

> In signal processing, group delay is the time delay of the amplitude
>   envelopes of the various sinusoidal components of a signal through a
>   device under test, and is a function of frequency for each component.

Back to your question...

> does a standard 1st order all pass filter provide a linear phase
>   shift? if not, what circuit provides a linear phase shift similary to
>   a Bessel filter, whilst providing linear amplitude response?

With reference to the picture above, you should be able to see that a 1st order circuit doesn't provide linear phase shift however, if you increase the number of stages then you get an improvement.

The picture was taken from [Chapter 16 Active Filter Design Techniques by Texas Instruments](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwj6steS0NfZAhVnKsAKHTzCC94QFggpMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Felectro.uv.es%2Fasignaturas%2Fea2%2Farchivos%2Fsloa088.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1-U3WRL-F7qaWDquwZMTwc)

Comment: Yes, the term I'm looking for is group delay. What im looking for is linear phase shift in the transition area, it seems from the picture you posted that it is semi-linear only in the pass-band, is it correct how Im reading that?

Comment: Yes, but you can make the pass and bigger to accommodate your maximum frequency

Comment: What about the transition frequency range?

Comment: What I mean is, is the phase shift in the transition range linear?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by transition range. If you mean the point where the ground delay falls down then no it can't be.

Comment: For my previous comment I meant "group delay" not "ground delay"!

Answer (score 0):

An allpass filter  is not given by its topology, but by its transfer function. A linear-phase allpass is given only by its type, which, in this case, is only Bessel. There are approximations to linear phase, but those have (equi-)ripples in the group delay which converge to zero as the order goes to inifinity (practically never, thus they always have ripples).
*[@LvW is right, this part is confusing, so I will try to explain what I meant below]*

As the other answer says, a 1st order is never a linear phase, but the book from which the link is quoted is only vaguely presented and, unfortunately, deceptive. The graphs you see plotted are the group delays of *Bessel* allpass filters, which does not mean that *all* allpass filters have the same response.

Since the allpass is made up from the denominator of an all-pole filter, together with its conjugate as a numerator -- correctly said in the book --, the filter can have any roots (and zeroes), which means the group delay can take any shape -- omitted in the book, and wrongly implied that all allpass are linear phase.

To illustrate, here are the responses of three 4th order allpass filters, a Bessel (black), a Butterworth (blue), and a 1dB ripple Chebyshev (red) who is frequency-scaled to match the Butterworth, for better comparison in group delay:

[image: comp]

As you can see, the group delays are typical of the three types of filters: linear for Bessel, linear for about half the bandwidth for Butterworth followed by one bump towards fc, and Chebyshev with linear group delay for approximately a quarter bandwidth followed by growing ripples.

To conclude:

- an allpass is not necessarily linear-phase;
- if you want a linear-phase, you need a Bessel-type transfer function;
- and if you want (as you say):

> a linear phase shift similary to a Bessel filter

then you need an *approximated*-linear-phase, which has this group delay response (blue), compared to the Bessel (red), for a 4th order comparison:

[image: approx]

IMHO, best stick to Bessel, I don't understand why the approximation exists, really, since for the same order filters Bessel will win hands down, everytime.

---

The topology for allpass filters needs to accomodate the needed transfer function, that is a Hurwitz polynomial as the denominator, and its conjugate as the numerator. This will give its constant *magnitude* response, but does not guarantee the linearity of the phase.

The denominator comes from a lowpass, which usually comes from the known types of filters, Butterworth, Chebyshev, Halpern, Bessel, etc, and they all need to be all-pole transfer functions (i.e. no zeroes), so that when the conjugate denominator is used as the numerator, the zeroes that the resulting transfer function will have will be the mirrored poles. Since the denominator has the roots on the left-hand side (implicit stability criterion), the zeroes will be mirrored on the imaginary axis, thus on the right-hand side. Since they are zeroes, they do not contribute to the instability of the filter.

Now, since there is no standard for how poles are placed, you can have any transfer function that can form a lowpass and, further on, be transformed into an allpass. This means that the lowpass prototypes can be non-linear phase, just as well. In fact, the Bessel filter is the only one that approximates this with sufficient precision -- nothing is perfect, and Bessel is an approximation to \$\exp(-st)\$, which gets better the higher the order.

Therefore, what I meant in the beginning, was that just as you can use various topolgies to form filters, such as Sallen-Key, or multiple-feedback, etc, you can use any topology that satisfies the existing allpass transfer function, and that the one that decides *how* the allpass response will be is the transfer function which, itself, is derived from a lowpass prorotype: if this prototype has linear phase, the allpass will have, too. I hope I made it a bit clearer, I'm not a master of words, let alone translated ones. :-)

Comment: With all respect  I have the impression that the above answer could cause some confusion. Of course, an allpass filter (which has a CONSTANT gain over frequency) is "given by its topolgy" (as an example: 1st-order allpass in the shown figure). All other mentioned filters (Bessel, Butterworth, Chebyshev) are no allpass but lowpass filters. The fact that the Bessel lowpass has a - more or less - constant group delay ("maximally flat") does not mean that it represents an allpass filter!

Comment: @LvW I meant that the topology is what is derived from a lowpass. A 1st order is a summer with a lowpass, same for 2nd order, etc. The values of the components, however, are given by the transfer function, which, in turn, is based on how the roots are placed in the s-plane, and those are, usually, calculated from the known lowpass prototypes. At least, that's what I meant to say. Now that I re-read it, you are right that it seems confusing. As for Bessel not being perfectly linear, that's the best we have and comes under the name Bessel, so that's what I'm using. I'll try to reformulate.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen so what you are saying is that one should start with a low-pass Bessel response and make a low-pass to all-pass transformation ? Is it possible to implement the resulting transfer function with simple 1st order all-pass sections like the one I mention in my question or should a different circuit be used? Like a bandpass summed with its original input perhaps?

Comment: @S.s. As mentioned, the allpass transfer function has poles on the left side of the imaginary axis, and mirrored versions of zeroes on the right of the imaginary axis. This is all the requirement for an alpass. What this also means is that you can have *any* poles, in whatever locations, as long as they satisfy the Hurwitz criterion (all of them on the left side), you can add zeroes that mirror the poles and have an allpass. Even if you fire the shortgun on the left side and consider the holes as poles, then mirror them as zeroes, and you still get an allpass. When I mentioned the prototype...

Comment: ...I did it because the other answer shows the group delay for a Bessel filter, which is only one type of filter, but declared as the generic response of an allpass, which is simply not the case (as said above), and also because, usually, you start from a certain requirement, which again, usually, falls in a certain known type of filter category, which produces a certain desired response, and it's this lowpass prototype that is transformed into an allpass. Usually. Ocasionally, one also brings a shotgun.